# Why is 'history' necessary in the Router of React-Router-Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, history

Normally, we use `react-router-dom` library in order to navigate to each page.
The usage is normally just like following and it is the same as what created by `create-react-app`.

`history.js` file

```
import * as history from 'history';

export default history.createBrowserHistory();
```

`index.js` file

```
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import history from '../history';

<Router history={history}></Router>
```

But I don't understand why `history` is necessary for the `Router`.
Is there anyone who can lend a hand to make me understand?

Comment: I have never passed the history prop to the Router component and it works fine. Can you share what tutorial are you following if any?

Comment: Also, you shouldn’t have to import the history object from another file. Abstraction is one thing but too much abstraction can lead to problems later on.

Answer (score 5):

`Router` is a low level interface for other routers such as BrowserRouter and HashRouter etc. So, if you are using `Router`, you must provide `history` object as it doesn't have its own.

But, if you don't want to provide your own history object, you can use `BrowserRouter`. It has its own `history` object.

See [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) and [Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router).

From docs:

> **Router:** The common low-level interface for all router components. Typically apps will use one of the high-level routers instead:
> `<BrowserRouter>`, `<HashRouter>`, `<MemoryRouter>` , `<NativeRouter>` or `<StaticRouter>`

Here is how to import these:

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
```

We can also use an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias) to import BrowserRouter:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
// Now Router is still a BrowserRouter
// Probably this causes the confusion
```

One common reason or **benefit** of using low level `Router` with your own `history` is that, this way, you can import and use `history` in any JS file (not only in a React Component).