# I am not able to use useHistory function in action creator file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am using react-router-dom and and redux. I use history.push("/") after dispatching but it shows error.
I want user to navigate to "/" after successfull authentication(USING GOOGLE)

```
    export const googleLogin = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    const doc = await db.collection("users").doc(response.user.uid).get();

    if (doc.exists) {
      await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(response.user.uid)
        .set(
          {
            accountDetail: {
              emailVerified: response.user.emailVerified,
              photoURL: response.user.photoURL,
            },
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
history.push("/")
    } else {
      await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(response.user.uid)
        .set({
          accountDetail: {
            userId: response.user.uid,
            displayName: response.user.displayName,
            email: response.user.email,
            photoURL: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
            accountCreatedAt: Date.now(),
          },
        });
history.push("/")
    }
      } catch (error) {
        await dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: error.message });
      }
    };
```

Comment: ERROR:-    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. Check again before continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `useHistory` hook in your action creator file because it is neither a React function component nor a custom hook.

As per [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions), a React Hook, e.g. `useHistory`, can only be used in a function component or in a custom hook.

But, if you want to access `history` object outside a React component, you can create your own `history` object and provide it to `Router` (from react-router-dom) as shown below:

Create a file, **history.js:**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Use `Router` and provide it your `history` object:

```
import history from '../path/to/history'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

// ...

return (
  <Router history={history}>
    <App/>
  </Router>
)
```

Now, you can easily import and use `history` in action creator file.

**Any js file:**

```js
import history from '../path/to/history'

// ...

history.push("/some/path")
```

Related: [Why is 'history' necessary in the Router of React-Router-Dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876991/2873538)

---

**Note:** Using `Router` doesn't stop you from using `useHistory` hook or `withRouter` HOC as you would normally use i.e. you can still use the hook or HOC in other React components to get the `history`.