# How to use useHistory() hook outside functional component in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-hooks, browser-history

I have a function in a separate js file that checks status codes received from Api requests, and depending on the code this function needs to perform some actions:

```
function handleResponseCodes(res) {
    try {
        if (res.status ===200 ) {
            return res.json();
        } else if (res.status === 404) {
            // here I need to redirect to /help
        } else if (!res.ok) {
            alert("Error")
        } else {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.data;
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

and then this function is used like this with fetch requests.( project will have 100+ api requests so this way makes the process easy to follow).

```
fetch(url, obj)
.then((res) => handleResponseCodes(res)
```

If res.code === 404 I need to redirect the user to /help url, problem is that when I try to use useHistory() hook like this:

```
import {useHistory) from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory()

//and in the function
else if (res.status === 404) {
// here I need to redirect to /help

history.push("/help")
```

I get error saying that useHistory hook must be used only in functional components. Is there a React way to redirect/push user to the /help from outside functional component?(basically from inside a function)

Comment: [How to use useHistory outside a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67347981/2873538)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass history as a parameter like this

```
...inside function component
const history = useHistory();
console.log(history)
//call function here
yourFunc(history)
```

Comment: I tried (like history.push) and it says can't read push of undefined.

Comment: you can try to log history before function call and let me know what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document.location.href = '/help'`

Answer (score 0):

Good question. We have so many api calls and have to handle those responses accordingly.
What I want to mention here is the close relation between routing and UI(for example, ProfilePage component).

According to [Hook rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), we can't use hook function outside the React component, so we have to use the ways like @Zhang and @istar's answers.

But split the routing and component isn't a good practice. Of course some developers use routing config file for routing, but changing the url is usually being done in component.
I think routing is also one part of component.

So I want to recommend you that do the routing inside the component. Please take the result of response handling function and do the routing according to its result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem because of previous build functions.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function ReactComponent () {
   const history = useHistory();

// some arrow function inside main react component 
    const someHandler = ( response, history ) => {
    outsideFunction( response, history );
};

}
export default ReactComponent;
```

you can do as you like, but i am breaking it to two functions.

```
export function outsideFunction ( response, history ) {

if ( response.status === 201 ) {
    checkedSubmitTypeHandler( location );
    redirectPage(history);        
    return true;
}
}

export function redirectPage (history) {
     return history.push(`/help`);
}
```

So, here is what happening that, you getting response wherever, Inside react main component or you handling in some other exported function. Passing the parameter through the arrow functions used inside react component.

It's not best practice to do it like this.
You should create a useHistoryHook which will be resuable in your application and you can call it like this.

// history.js page inside src

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

// useHistorypush component

```
import React from 'react';
import history from '../../history';

const useHistoryPush = (pathname,onLoadWait = 30) => {
  const refContainer = React.useRef(false);

  setTimeout(() => {
      refContainer.current = true;
  }, onLoadWait); 

  return (link) => {
    if (refContainer.current) {
        history.push(link);
    }
    };
   };

   export default useHistoryPush;
```

// implementation inside page

```
import useHistoryPush from '../use-history-push';

const Reactcomponent = () => {
   const push = useHistoryPush();

    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (successResponse) {
        // on some condition you can call it inside useeffect and it will redirect to the url mention inside *push
      push(`/help`);
    }
}, [successResponse, push]);

}
export default Reactcomponent;
```